# Getting unhandled error event when running Yeoman

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman, bower, nvm

When I run Yeoman I get this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
```

Does anyone know what this might be? I don't know if it's an OS problem, but I did recently get a new computer which was upgraded to Yosemite. This happened the first time I ran Yeoman after setting up my environment.

Comment: Did you run bower install and npm install?

Comment: Yeah, and it still gives me the error.

Comment: I got that running Android Ionic: `ionic serve`

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error with Yeoman. The default gulp task is 'clean'.

I commented out this line:

```
gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
  //$.del(['dist/', '.tmp/'], done);
});
```

You could either try resolving the issue with the `del` npm module or use `gulp-clean` instead.

On a side note, if you need to run the server, run `gulp serve`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running an stable version of *npm*:

```
> npm install -g npm@latest
```

Best.